# Android car navigation library

Tags: android, navigation, gps, fragment, openstreetmap

Is there any library to integrate car navigation on my own android application? I would like to add a navigation part (like a fragment) on the main screen of my app. I don't know if there is an API, library or open source proyect that allows me to use it. Maybe one that uses openstreetmap?

Comment: Please see http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Android and http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Routing/offline_routers

Comment: you can do it by integrating a navigation SDK: Telenav's SDK(http://developer.skobbler.com/), deCarta's SDK (http://www.decarta.com/products/tbt_navigation.html), Sygic's SDK(https://www.sygic.com/en/business:try-sygic-sdk), etc.

Comment: Take a look at [GraphHopper](https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/GraphHopper).